# Popular Medical Halacha Poskim for Modern Medicine?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, medicine

Like the question asks, I have recently been intrigued by the topic of Medical Halacha and am looking around for some of the major poskim on the issue, be that early or recent. I know Rav Moshe Feinstien Z"tl answered many shailos regarding this topic but I am looking to know about other poskim as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the Tzitz Eliezer was world renowned for this

Comment: Agree, Tzitz Eliezer (as the posek for Shaarei Tzedek hospital). Also, the Nishmas Avraham, based on conversations with R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach.

Comment: @Shalom I'm fairly certain he was not the Poseik of the ST hospital. He just Davened in a Shul near there and they asked him lots of questions.

Comment: may want to ask Rabbi Akiva Tatz

Comment: Are you looking for a list of names or written works? Living poskim or not necessarily?

Comment: @user6591 I'm looking for a list of written works. They don't have to be necessarily living

Comment: @PloniAlmoni You should [edit] your question to clarify things that people are unsure about, not just explain in comments. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: _Rambam_ was renowned for this also.

Comment: @msh210 I don't think he was.

Comment: @doubleAA , its not a misnomer to call the Tzitz Eliezer the "posek" of Sharre tzedek,maybe unofficial posek is better,but it is known that he answered all the big questions for them specifically and was recognized by all hospital personnel

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I'm good right now

Answer (score 5):

Rabbi Avraham S. Avraham has written a few popular books including Nishmat Avraham on Medical Halacha that have been translated into English, too.
He was very close with Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach as well as Rabbi Eliezer Waldenberg (the Tzitz Eliezer) whom some of his Teshuvos are addressed to.
The English books are available at http://www.artscroll.com/Categories/NIA.html and the Hebrew text is available online at http://hebrewbooks.org/51473

Comment: +1 I'll just add that this work was written amazingly well (imho). The explanation of the medical subject and the halachik opinions never overshadow each other in any way. I especially appreciated his lengthily discussion about end of life issues.

Comment: This book is a very good source, written by  a MD and TCh,

Answer (score 3):

[Practical Medical Halacha
by Fred Rosner, Association of Orthodox Jewish Scientists](http://www.alibris.com/Practical-Medical-Halacha-Fred-Rosner/book/5280989)

Dr. Rosner has written extensively on the subject of medical halacha and is considered a very good source. You can find other sources for his writings and shiurim using google.

Additionally there is a site which has a number of links to [Medical Ethics and halacha](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/index.html) which would seem to be of interest.

Comment: Dr. Rosner studied with Rav Moshe Feinstein, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Along with Nishmat Avraham that Zvi mentioned, there is also the Encyclopedia of Jewish Medical Ethics by Avraham Steinberg. [https://www.amazon.com/Encyclopedia-Jewish-Medical-Avraham-Steinberg/dp/1583305920](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1583305920)

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Dr. Akiva Tatz. He's contemporary  (alive), brilliant and accessible.

Comment: The OP asked for "some of the major poskim on the issue". While this is a subjective term, I think it is debatable whether R. Tatz qualifies. I am under the impression that he is more an assembler of opinion on a given topic, than a major posek in his own right.

Comment: Like you said - it's subjective. When it comes to Medical Halacha he's on the ball. I'm not sure if he's assembling opinion but even that requires alot of knowledge. The "major poskim" turn to him for these issues. For what Ploni wants, Akiva Tatz will be just fine.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but which poskim of the caliber of R. Moshe Feinstein (mentioned by the OP as an example), or even in his ballpark turn to him?